# JQuery Dynamic Table Add/Remove

Tags: jquery, crud

I am looking for a JQuery plug which allows to create and submit a list of dynamic items.

Interface:

```
<Select Item> - <Select Quantity> <Add>
```

When you add it creates a table which has the items listed and the option to delete. Then the user can submit and the request will be processed. So far all of the plugins I've found can Add/Remove elements but they don't create a table. It's just a input box that keeps replicating itself.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must it be a plugin? Ive done something similar with a little code on my own:

```js
  
  var fileList = [];
  
  fileList.push({fileName: "somefile1", fileExt: ".jpg", fileSize: 128000});
  fileList.push({fileName: "somefile2", fileExt: ".DOC", fileSize: 158930});
  fileList.push({fileName: "somefile3", fileExt: ".xml", fileSize: 3695200});
  CreateTable(fileList);
    
  
function CreateTable(fileList)
        {
            
            $("#fileList tbody").empty();
            for (var n = 0; n < fileList.length; n++) {
                $("#fileList tbody").append(
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + fileList[n].fileName + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + fileList[n].fileExt + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + Math.round(fileList[n].fileSize * .001) + " kb" + "</td>" +
                    "<td> <img src='/Content/Images/file_delete_small.png' width:50% height:50% class='btnDelete'/> </td>" +
                    "</tr>"                
                );
            }
            
            $(".btnDelete").on("click", Delete);
            $('#fileList').show()
        }


function Delete() {
            var deleteName = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
            var deleteExt = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
            var deleteFile = deleteName + '.' + deleteExt;
            var rowNumber = $(this).closest('tr').index()+1;
  
            document.getElementById("fileList").deleteRow(rowNumber);
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:50%" id="fileList" class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>File Type</th>
            <th>File Size</th>
            <th>Remove File</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the fileList array could be populated from some other formData that holds onto the files and upon submission you can handle that list however you want depending on your framework and such. In my case, I was letting a user select files from local disk and upload them upon submit. I had to remove and change some of the code to make it more generic so you might be able to use it easier. We can discuss that further if you would like.

Comment: no problem! Let me know if you have any questions that I might be able to clarify. I have a fully developed file upload utility in production that this JQuery is a small piece of and I am sure I can help circumvent some of the hurdles I ran into.